# PHP - Cant store record inside database

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a html file called `contact.html` and `connectivity.php`. Inside the `contact.html` I set `form action="Conectivity.php"`. However,when I run `contact.html` and click send button, it should save the record inside my database, but when i clicked the button it only show me the entire code inside `connectivity.php`.

Here is my code in `connectivity.php`:

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'practice');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','');

$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$query = "INSERT INTO contact (contactName,contactEmail,message)VALUES('$name','$email','$message')";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if($result)
{
    echo "Successfully updated database";
} 
else
{
    die('Error: '.mysql_error($con));
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Are you actually running a local web server, or just opening the HTML file directly in your web browser? Seeing the full PHP code implies that your PHP was never executed.

Comment: **By building SQL statements with outside variables, you are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks.**  Also, any input data with single quotes in it, like a name of "O'Malley", will blow up your SQL query. Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app.  http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started, and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has many examples in detail.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski i have installed xampp and create a database inside phpMyAdmin

Comment: Just having the web server present doesn't make it active. Are you accessing the file via something like `http://localhost/contact.html`? If it looks like `file:///path/to/contact.html` then the web server isn't processing it.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski opps~it does look like file:///path/to/contact.html.How can imake it to accessing via http://localhost/contact.html?

Comment: Don't know- follow the directions for xampp.  You need to put your HTML and PHP files in whatever directory xampp expects the web server DocumentRoot to be, but I don't know what that is. When you get them there, access `http://localhost/contact.html`.  Meanwhile, try going to `http://localhost` and see if xampp puts a temporary file there with further instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say "it only show me the entire code inside connectivity.php" -- it sounds like you don't have a web server installed and are seeing PHP code, because it's not executing your script.  You need to install a web server.

**Note: if you access a file like `file:///foo/Connectivity.php`, you will also have this problem -- it has to be over HTTP for the web server to execute the PHP.** You must access the file via HTTP, like `http://localhost/Connectivity.php` or whatever your local server name is instead of localhost.

Please also check your spelling. Your question says, `i set form action="conectivity.php"`. Your file is named `Connectivity.php` -- please confirm that you spelled it correctly in the `<form>` tag.

Also, [don't use mysql_*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1) - use MySQLi or PDO instead. You *must* use prepared statements; your current code is extremely vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: i do installed a web server called xampp but it still doesnt work.

Comment: Create a new page, `test.php`, and put the following code in it: `<?php echo "Foo"; ?>` Browse to that page. If you see anything other than `Foo`, then either (1) you aren't accessing the page correctly or (2) xampp isn't running correctly.

Comment: I still see the entire code.How can i accessing the page correctly because i think the xampp is running correctly.Maybe is the accessing problem?

Comment: Then where should i put the file test.php to?

Comment: It needs to be in whatever directory your web server is using as its home directory. What URL are *you* using to access it?

Comment: My accessing url is something like this file:///path/to/contact.html

Comment: Please see my note above -- the problem is accessing it via `file:///` -- you *must* use `http://` (or `https://` if you have an SSL certificate installed).

Comment: Thank you, I have solved the problem and i will use mysqli instead of mysql. I am totally new in this so thank you for all the advices.